# How to determine the contribution rate of a specific unit test case?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tdd, code-coverage

**Background**

I am aware of the principles of [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) (Test Driven Development) and unit testing, as well of different coverage metrics. Currently, i am working on an Linux C/C++ project, where 100% [branch coverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage) should be reached.

**Question**

Does anybody know a technique/method to automatically identify those unit test cases, that contribute most to reach a specific coverage goal? Each unit-test could then be associated with contribution rate (in percent). Having this numbers, unit-test cases could be ordered by their  contribution-rate.

Comment: I am interested to know why a test case with a low coverage is not better than the others. The other ones should be covered by normal operation,

Comment: @Ed Heal I did not mean a test case with a lower test case is not better! I am interested in ordering test cases by their contribution rate.

Comment: Why? Just run all of them. Have a beer in the pub next door when they are running

Comment: @Ed Heal Some test cases consume more run-time than others, while their contribution-rate differs. This could help to identify those test cases that consume huge amount of run-time and less coverage contribution rate.

Comment: Do you want to measure *branches tested* or *branches tested per second*?

Comment: @Beta Branches tested

Comment: I agree with Ed, this is flawed. You want to run tests with higher coverage first because time is a factor, implying that those tests are more valuable. This is a fallacy. You lowest-rated test might reveal the most critical bug. Regarding improvement of your test cases, I think that coverage/time is a poor indicator of tests that need improvement/have room for improvement.

Comment: I hate this approach to coverage and I feel you have missed the point. This approach would lead to tests that cover code but provide lttle value. The real value of code-coverage is in identifying what you haven't covered by tests i.e. were your testing is weak.

Comment: @MartinEttl Having a test ordering strategy only makes sense if you assume that the test suite can legitimately be stopped at some point IMO. In my experience, a valid rationale is to run tests that recently failed first, because they are the most likely to fail again. If they do fail, you can immediately stop the line and start fixing them, thus saving time. I don't see what your ordering strategy brings to the table if you're aiming for complete correctness at the end of the day.

Answer (score 0):

The [Greedy algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) can help here. In simple words:

1. From all tests select the one with the highest coverage
2. Calculate the coverage delta between remaining candidates and tests selected already.
3. Pick the candidate that gives the biggest delta
4. Repeat as of step 2 until all tests are put into the ranking

As a result you'll get a sorting that looks like the one generated by [Squish Coco](https://www.froglogic.com/coco) for GNU coreutils:

[image: Optimized Execution Order]

Typically the benefit of each extra test will go down the more tests you add. Some of them may be even have zero contribution to the total coverage.

A good case for this sorting is an optimal execution order for smoke tests that only have limited time to run. For a complete testing you better always run the whole suite, of course.